# Печать нескольких страниц одним кликом

Tags: php, bash, javascript

Котаны, всем привет.
Задача, напечатать кучу страниц, выделив несколько чекбоксов и нажав одну кнопку.
Хочу упростить работу техническим отделам во многих филиалах.
Сейчас тех. отделы печатают каждую страницу отдельно, что занимает очень много времени.

```
window.print(); //На каждой отдельной странице.
```

Comment: чего бы для печати не вывести все страницы на одну ?

Comment: Мне в голову пришел примитивный и диковатый способ. После выбора checkbox'ов, нужно просто сформировать страницу, которая будет содержать список iframe/frame по одной штуке на каждую страницу. Это можно сделать даже на левом сайте.

Comment: Как вариант, но дикость таки да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял есть веб документация с постраничной навигацией . Задача состоит в том чтобы выбрав чекбоксами нужные страницы (или диапазоны страниц, или раздел/ы) для печати.
Вам подойдёт скриптик который будет отправлять Ajax ом массив с адресами страниц отдельному блоку который будет выполнять печать сраницы после чего перезагружать страницу на следующую в массиве передавая POST массив сос списком страниц и указанием какая страница будет следующая. На всех страницах(или только в индексе если у Вас CMS) вставить перехватчик событий для запуска печати.

Answer (score 0):

Крайне не рекомендую печатать html страницы. Очень много ньюансов в зависимости от броузера и т.д. В общим ад. Переводите всё в pdf и печатайте его. Результат будет всегда одинаковым.

Comment: страницы простые, ничего страшного нет.